# Is there a function that returns a built in dataset based on a string parameter in R?

Tags: r, dataset

Is there a function that returns one of the built-in datasets based on the name as a string in R? 
Until now, to get the dataset e.g. *mtcars*, we just call the *mtcars* function.
What I need is a function that returns the dataset based on the name as a string e.g.

```
my.data <- get.dataset("mtcars")
```

Comment: You can use `get("mtcars")` or load with `data("mtcars")`

Comment: `mtcars` is not a function, it is an object, just like if you first do `x <- 1`, then `x` recalls its value. In this case, `mtcars` is an object that originally resides in the `datasets` package and its namespace, and is by default available on the R prompt just by typing `mtcars`. The first time you *modify* one of these datasets, its value is copied and assigned in the local environment; if you want to do that explicitly, the [`data(.)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/data.html) function will do that (and `data(.)` is the canonical answer to your question).